# Can Azure Service Principal Update Its Own Passwords?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to use an Azure service principal to programmatically:
1. add/delete passwords for other services principal , and
2. add/delete passwords for itself

1 is easy to do.

But I can't seem to do 2 due to the following error. Is #2 possible? How?

```
graphrbac.PasswordCredentialsUpdateParameters failed:
graphrbac.ApplicationsClient#UpdatePasswordCredentials: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" 
Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2019-06-06T22:19:35","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"<ID>"}}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is #2 possible? How?

Yes, it is possible.

Just add your service principal to the  [`Application Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-administrator) directory role in your tenant, no need to add other permissions, it will work(there may be some delay).

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> click `Application administrator` -> `Add assignment` -> search by your AD App name(service principal name) -> select it -> `Select`.

**My test sample:**

I test it with powershell, in other languages, it should also work.

Add password:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "<TenantId>" -ApplicationId "<ApplicationId>" -CertificateThumbprint "D0F0B179xxxxx6E41833FDE5947"
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId <ObjectId>
```

[image]

Remove password(it returns no content when successful):

```
$password = Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId <ObjectId>
Remove-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId <ObjectId> -KeyId $password.KeyId
```

**Besides**, you could check the screenshot in my test sample and that in the portal, make sure the service principal add/delete passwords **for itself**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The "Application Administrator" was what I was missing.

Comment: @ShangjianDing Glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to update your service principle meanwhile caught an error.

As the error said you don't have permission for this operation.

**Reason of Error:** You may not have sufficient permission on your application for this operation.

**Action To Do:**

To do that you have to assign following permission on your application. Please follow the below steps:

1. Login to `azure portal`
2. Click on `azure active directory`
3. App registrations
4. Select you application
5. API Permission
6. Add Permission
7. Microsoft Graph
8. Application permission
9. In `Directory` select `Directory.Read.All`
10. In `Application` select `Application.ReadWrite.All`
11. Add Permission
12. Grant admin consent for `YourTennant`

See the screen shot below:

[image]

> **Note:** You also need to have at least `Contributor` directory role on that application. As the `Contributor` can create and manage all types of
>   Azure resources but can’t grant access to others.

Comment: Thank you. But I already have all those permissions objects associated with it. The "Application Administrator" role was what I was missing, which Joey pointed out above.

Comment: Yeah application administration also alright. I have also specified that on `note` part. At least need `Contributor Role` But `application administration` higher then that. It has privilege also. Thanks