# How to use New-AzADSpCredential to add certificate credentials

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am using App Registrations to deploy resources and the certificate is expiring. I am trying to write a script to add a new cert to extend the life of this Service Principal but no matter who I login as (myself, a colleague, the Service Principal itself) I get the following error:

```
New-AzADSpCredential : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. At X:\XXX\XXXX\XXXXX\Add-NewDmfCertificate.ps1:496 char:63 
+ ... cipalName | New-AzADSpCredential -CertValue $credValue -StartDate $ce ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-AzADSpCredential], Exception 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.NewAzureADSpCredentialCommand
```

EDIT:

Some comments have caused me to expound on my question because I'm not sure I'm being clear.

English is my first language and I do understand the base meaning of the message. What I don't understand is how to address the issue. I am an owner of the Service Principal. My colleague is an owner. The Service Principal should be able to administer itself (I would think). I have tested this on Service Principals I have created and it works. So I have to wonder: am I doing this correctly? If not, how do I add certificate credentials to an SP? If I am doing it correctly, where do I set the permissions to allow either the SP (preferably) or an AD user to make this change?

EDIT2:

I am a terrible user. Thank you for pointing out that I neglected to include a code example. Not sure how much it helps but I know enough to include it regardless of my thoughts.

```
param (
    [string] $ServicePrincipalName
)
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificateEx (you'll forgive me for leaving this part out :)  )

$rawCert = $cert.RawData
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($rawCert)

Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $ServicePrincipalName | New-AzADSpCredential -CertValue $credValue -StartDate $cert.NotBefore -EndDate $cert.NotAfter
```

Comment: well, this only means all of these do not have enough permissions to do that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it does mean that. I've done enough Azure stuff to wonder if I'm simply doing this wrong. That's why I phrased the question the way I did: How am I supposed to do this? If it's this way why doesn't it work and if it's not what way should I use?

Comment: well, ironically you are not showing how you are doing that, so I can only guess how, but this operation needs Azure AD permissions, not Azure RBAC, so your owner permissions mean nothing here. You need Application Read\Write permissions. easiest way of getting that is assigning yourself application administrator Azure AD role

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your user accounts are the `Owner` of the service principal(**`Enterprise application`**), the command `New-AzADSpCredential` will work.

I test with a normal user who is an `Owner` of the service principal, it works fine.

[image]

[image]

---

> What I don't understand is how to address the issue. I am an owner of the Service Principal. My colleague is an owner.

In your case, I suppose you may misunderstand the concept of the `AD App(App registration)` and `service principal(Enterprise application)`, they are different, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals). You may be an `Owner` of the AD App instead of the service principal(just a guess:-)), if so, you are not able to run the command `New-AzADSpCredential` as a normal user.

Also note, when use `New-AzADSpCredential` to create the certificate credential(key credential) successfully, you will not find it in the `App registration -> your AD App -> Certificates & secrets` page, because the certificate credential of the service principal is not the AD App's. You could get it via `Get-AzADServicePrincipalCredential`.

If you find you are the `Owner` of the AD App(App registration), actually you can use [`New-AzADAppCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-3.1.0), check [Example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-3.1.0#examples), or this [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) module command [`New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationkeycredential?view=azureadps-2.0).

*Sample:*

```
Connect-AzureAD
$cer = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=TodoListDaemonWithCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
$bin = $cer.GetRawCertData()
$base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)
$bin = $cer.GetCertHash()
$base64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)
$keyid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString() 
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId "<object-id of the AD App>" -CustomKeyIdentifier $base64Thumbprint  -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $base64Value -StartDate $cer.NotBefore -EndDate $cer.NotAfter
```

[image]

Then you can find it on the App registration page like below.

[image]

> The Service Principal should be able to administer itself (I would think).

Yes, it is possible. But you need to give the [`Application Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-administrator)/[`Global Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#global-administrator--company-administrator) directory role to your service principal, similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486068/can-azure-service-principal-update-its-own-passwords/56487271#56487271).

Comment: Added myself as user to the Enterprise Application and it worked fine. Thank you for pointing out the difference.