# How to reset credentials of an Azure service principal using an automation account PowerShell runbook?

Tags: azure, powershell, credentials, azure-automation, service-principal

I'm trying to reset the password credentials of a service principal (let's call it SP1) through the following PowerShell commands:

```
Remove-AzADSpCredential -ObjectId  <SP1_objectId> -Force
$Password = New-AzADSpCredential -ObjectId <SP1_objectId>
```

This works well when I run it through the PowerShell by my own user account, which has an Owner role assigned to SP1.

I also have this code in a runbook in an automation account with a "run as account" service principal (let's call it SP2).

I assigned the ownership of SP1 to SP2 as well through the command `Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner` and confirmed it through `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner`.

I expected the runbook to be able to run the  `Remove-AzADSpCredential` command on the SP1 after making its service principal the owner of SP1.  But I get the following error:

> Remove-AzADSpCredential : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. At line:43 char:9 + Remove-AzADSpCredential -ObjectId $key.Name -Force + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-AzADSpCredential], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.RemoveAzureADSpCredentialCommand

And the same error for `New-AzADSpCredential` command as well.

I thought maybe the ownership of SP1 should be assigned to the App for the run as account, instead of its service principal.
So I also ran the following:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId <SP1_ObjectId> -RefObjectId <runasaccount_app_ObjectId>
```

But this wasn't possible, as I got the error:

> Code: Request_BadRequest
> Message: The reference target 'Application_xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx' of type 'Application' is invalid for the 'owners' reference.

So I assume the ownership should have been assigned only to SP2, and not to the app.

I looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306069/how-to-use-new-azadspcredential-to-add-certificate-credentials) but the accepted answer says

> If your user accounts are the Owner of the service principal(Enterprise application), the command New-AzADSpCredential will work.

which is true in my case, and yet, it's not working when running the runbook.

I also looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486068/can-azure-service-principal-update-its-own-passwords/56487271#56487271) and it seems I need to do the #1 which the OP describes as easy to do.

Any input on how to do this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Hi Joy,
Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately, I don't have access rights to set AAD app permissions myself. Waiting on the responsible team to do that in my organization. I'll accept your answer as soon as I get the permission and verify the app works. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a service principal to add/remove credentials for another service principal, it is different from using a user account to do that.

> I assigned the ownership of SP1 to SP2 as well through the command `Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner` and confirmed it through `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner`.

This way is correct, but not only the `Owner`, also you need to give an `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` *Application permission* in `Azure Active Directory Graph` (Not `Microsoft Graph`)API after that.

Navigate to the `API permissions` of your automation account corresponded AD App in the portal -> add the permission like below, don't forget to click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button at last.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then test it in the runbook, it works fine.

```
New-AzADSpCredential -ObjectId xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

[image]

The combination of `Owner` and `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` is the minimum privilege in this case, there are also other ways, you can also give the `Application Administrator` directory role as you saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486068/can-azure-service-principal-update-its-own-passwords/56487271#56487271) or `Application.ReadWrite.All` *Application permission* in `Azure Active Directory Graph`, both will work.